# Joi validation : how to make field required if one of two fields exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

My question is: if I want to make **c** required if **b** or **c** (not both) exists how can achieve this using Joi validation? please see Json example below:

{
a: '1',
b: '2',
c: '3'
}

can any body give a way in Joi validation to achieve the above?

Comment: can you explain better what you wanna validate? if there is a B then a C is required just that?  what's the `not both` part about? make C required if you have a C?

Answer (score 0):

To make one of the two required, you can use [`xor`](https://joi.dev/api/?v=15.1.1#objectxorpeers) which

> Defines an exclusive relationship between a set of keys where one of them is required but not at the same time

```
.xor('b', 'c')
```

```js
const schema = joi.object({
    a: joi.string(),
    b: joi.string(),
    c: joi.string()
}).xor('b', 'c');  // <<<<<<<< using xor()

console.log(schema.validate({a:"1", b:"2"})) // passes the validation
console.log(schema.validate({a:"1", c:"3"})) // passes the validation
console.log(schema.validate({a:"1"})) // returns with error
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/joi@17.9.2/dist/joi-browser.min.js"></script>
```